# ViewController access data

Tags: ios, xcode

Today i would ask you if there is a way to call a method of another view controller just not initializing it or just how to get that viewController as a global variable declared in .h file.
Help me please.
I'm using a PageViewController and I have to use a method of the contentViewController alredy initialized.

here I create my ViewControllers:

```
- (void)createTheContent {

NSLog(@"createTheContent");
pageController = nil;
//[pageController removeFromParentViewController];
//[pageController awakeFromNib];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin] forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options: options];

pageController.dataSource = self;
[[pageController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 365)];

initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
[pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[pageController view]];
[pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


}
```

here are my propertys in .h file:

```
        contentViewController *initialViewController;
}

//Page View Controller Properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageContent;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pageStrings;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
```

Comment: what is your `contentViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question title, it seems you are trying to access your controller to get some data back.

In this case, my suggestion would be creating a "model" (as in Model-View-Controller) in your design, and make that model accessible from everywhere in your app. An easy way to accomplish the latter point is to make the model class a singleton; or you might make it a class with only class-methods to give access to the data. See also [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063984/creating-a-global-class-objective-c/13064008#13064008) about the same issue for some sample code.

After reading your edit, I would suggest the following:

1. add to your `contentViewController` class a property say it `dataSource`;
2. `dataSource` is of type `contentViewControllerDataSource` and provides the method to access all required data, e.g.:

   ```
   @protocol contentViewControllerDataSource <NSObject>
     -(NSString*)textViewContent;
   @end
   ```
3. before adding `contentViewController` to the page controller, set its `dataSource` property:

   ```
   initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
   initialViewController.dataSource = self;
   NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
   [pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
   ```
4. let your `self` controller implement the `contentViewControllerDataSource` protocol:

   ```
   @interface DonKnowTheNameOfThisOne : UIViewController <contentViewControllerDataSource>

   ....

   @implementation DonKnowTheNameOfThisOne;

   ...
   - (NSString*)textViewContent {
      return value;
   }
   ```
5. from `contentViewController` you will be able to call:

   ```
   NSString* textViewContent = self.dataSource.textViewContent;
   ```

   or:

   ```
   self.dataSource.textViewContent = @"NEWVAL";
   ```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

After looking at your files:

Please, remove the `#import "ViewController.h"` directive at the beginning of `contentViewController.h`. That should fix the problem you had.

Another thing: I wrote at point 1 that `contentViewController` have the property `dataSource`; `ViewController` implements the `contentViewControllerDataSource` protocol and hosts the data that `contentViewController` would like to access. One class is the "client" of the data; the other "shares" the data through the delegate protocol that you can modify from outside. In your code both the `dataSource` and the protocol are assigned to the same `ViewController` class and this makes no sense. So, you can try an fix it: I am not sure now which class should be doing what, but you will know, I hope.

Comment: my contentViewController has a textView used to place strings. I have to call this contentViewController just to get the modified string...

Comment: could you post some code, just to have a clearer picture of what you are doing?

Comment: I would only like to see how you instantiate the two controllers; how you go from one to the other; where exactly you need to call the first from the second. Or just having some names of classes and variables, so that I can write some more meaningful sample code...

Comment: so, if I understand it correctly, you have one view controller which contains the textView; you add it a child view controller that is a page controller containing `initialViewController`; you would like to access the first view controller's textView data from `initialViewController'. Is this right?

Comment: yes it is right! when the user changes the text in the text view I have to replace the previous string object of an array with the new one!!

Comment: so i have to add in contentviewcontroller a protocol or a property? and if a property how can I write it?

Comment: donknowthenameofthisone is the viewController where I allocate the contentViewController?

Comment: you need to add both a protocol and a property; the protocol is a "named" description of the set of properties you define. as to writing to it, you simply say: see my edit... `donknowthenameofthisone` is the controller where you allocat contentViewcontroller (where I understood you have the text view).

Comment: yes, the textView is in contentViewController.. but the last two strings i have to call in my mainViwController not in my contentViewController right?

Comment: I think so, if there has been no misunderstanding. Please, try the code and if you find any problem with it, report it back.

Comment: writing the property like this: @property (strong, nonatomic) contentViewControllerDataSource *dataSource    gaves me an error...

Comment: what error? have you imported the header file where you define the protocol?

Comment: yes ant it says me unknown type name 'contentViewControllerDataSource'; did you mean 'contentViewController'?

Comment: but i imported the header file of the contentViewController and also the <contentViewControllerdataSource>

Comment: would you like to see it on github?

Comment: maybe better if i send you the files via e-mail because i'm not registered on github yet..

Comment: here it is: labs@freescapes.org

Comment: sorry, the property declaration is: `@property (weak, nonatomic) id<contentViewControllerDataSource> dataSource;` -- I suggest also to make it weak...

Comment: now it gives me an error when i put <contentViewControllerDataSource> in @interface: ViewController. how can i fix this?

Comment: if you want i can resend you all the files!

Comment: can you please correct the previous files that i sent and correct them for me? please!!!

Comment: I don't understand how to do it... can you correct my files and resend them to me please?

Comment: Con you explain it better please?